# You can't use `\lastsavedimageresourcepages' in vertical mode. error using TexLive 2018 on Linux

Tags: epstopdf, pgffor

Update:

Thanks for the comment below, adding `\the` before `\lastsavedimageresourcepages` in the MWE below worked! But why? I have thousands of places in all my latex files that uses this type of code without `\the` in there and that always worked.

So now I have go find and edit each place and add `\the` there? I do not understand why this change was made that will break current latex code.

---

### Original question

The MWE below gives this error when compiled with `lualatex` only on Linux Manjaro with fresh installation of TL 2018 on Vbox I did last night.

The same file compiles with lualatex with no error on another Linux ubuntu but with TeXLive which I have no updated for may be one or 2 month.   That is the only difference.

So it seems something broke in latest TL 2018?  Notice that this MWE is only meant to work on lualatex and not with pdflatex. As `\saveimageresource` is defined only when using `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pgffor}  
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\saveimageresource{math_228A_HW1.pdf}%use any other PDF here to run
\foreach \n in {1,...,\lastsavedimageresourcepages} % for lualatex
{
    \includegraphics[width=0.88\textwidth,page=\n]{math_228A_HW1}

}  

\end{document}
```

### Example where it fails

When I compile this on Linux with *latest* TL 2018, I get error

```
>uname -a
Linux me-pc 4.19.13-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Dec 29 15:43:56 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux

>which lualatex
/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux/lualatex
>
>
>lualatex --version
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.07.0 (TeX Live 2018)

>lualatex foo.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.07.0 (TeX Live 2018) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./foo.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>

luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.128 seconds
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/scripts/oberdiek/oberdiek.luatex.lua)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hluatex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-li
sts.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def)))
(./foo.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./foo.out) (./foo.out) ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
! You can't use `\lastsavedimageresourcepages' in vertical mode.
<argument> \lastsavedimageresourcepages 

l.15 }

?
```

### Example where it works

When I compile this on another Linux running TL 2018 but not updated yet, it works and compiles with no error:

```
>uname -a
Linux DESKTOP-7OK6FOH 4.4.0-17763-Microsoft #194-Microsoft 
Mon Dec 03 17:58:00 PST 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


>ls -l
total 584
-rwxrwxrwx 1 me me    325 Jan 24 02:03 foo.tex
-rwxrwxrwx 1 me me 594289 Jan 19 18:59 math_228A_HW1.pdf
>

>cat foo.tex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\saveimageresource{math_228A_HW1.pdf}
\foreach \n in {1,...,\lastsavedimageresourcepages} % for lualatex
{
    \includegraphics[width=0.88\textwidth,page=\n]{math_228A_HW1}

}
\end{document}
>

>
>which lualatex
/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux/lualatex
>

>lualatex --version
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.07.0 (TeX Live 2018)

>lualatex foo.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.07.0 (TeX Live 2018)
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./foo.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5

luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.168 seconds
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/scripts/oberdiek/oberdiek.luatex.lua)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hluatex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-li
sts.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex))
 (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def)))
No file foo.aux.
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}<./math
_228A_HW1.pdf>] [2<./math_228A_HW1.pdf>] [3<./math_228A_HW1.pdf>] [4<./math_228
A_HW1.pdf>] [5<./math_228A_HW1.pdf>] [6<./math_228A_HW1.pdf>] [7<./math_228A_HW
1.pdf>] [8<./math_228A_HW1.pdf>] [9<./math_228A_HW1.pdf>] [10<./math_228A_HW1.p
df>] [11<./math_228A_HW1.pdf>] [12<./math_228A_HW1.pdf>] [13<./math_228A_HW1.pd
f>] [14<./math_228A_HW1.pdf>] [15<./math_228A_HW1.pdf>] [16<./math_228A_HW1.pdf
>] [17<./math_228A_HW1.pdf>] [18<./math_228A_HW1.pdf>] [19<./math_228A_HW1.pdf>
] [20<./math_228A_HW1.pdf>] [21<./math_228A_HW1.pdf>] [22<./math_228A_HW1.pdf>]
(./foo.aux)

Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `foo.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.

)
 386 words of node memory still in use:
   2 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 4 attribute, 46 glue_spec
, 4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:63,3:9,4:1,5:23,6:3,7:24,8:5,9:27
</usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.
otf>
Output written on foo.pdf (22 pages, 595632 bytes).
Transcript written on foo.log.
>
```

This is the file list on the TL 2018 that I just installed fresh:

```
*File List*
 article.cls    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
  size11.clo    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
hyperref.sty    2018/11/30 v6.88e Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2018/09/07 v3.3 Provides the ifpdf switch
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
luatex-loader.sty    2016/05/16 v0.6 Lua module loader (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2018/09/10 v0.29 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2018/11/30 v6.88e Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hluatex.def    2018/11/30 v6.88e Hyperref driver for luaTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
  pgffor.sty    2019/01/05 v3.1 (3.1)
  pgfrcs.sty    2019/01/05 v3.1 (3.1)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
graphicx.sty    2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  luatex.def    2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for luatex
 nameref.sty    2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
     foo.out
     foo.out
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 ***********
```

This is list of files on the other linux where it compiles OK and I have no yet updated TL on it:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size11.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
hyperref.sty    2018/11/30 v6.88e Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2018/09/07 v3.3 Provides the ifpdf switch
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
luatex-loader.sty    2016/05/16 v0.6 Lua module loader (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2018/09/10 v0.29 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2018/11/30 v6.88e Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hluatex.def    2018/11/30 v6.88e Hyperref driver for luaTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)
  pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfkeys.sty
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
graphicx.sty    2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  luatex.def    2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for luatex
 nameref.sty    2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
     foo.out
     foo.out
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 ***********

)
```

Looking at the versions above, I see that `pgffor.sty` was updated on :

```
  pgffor.sty    2019/01/05 v3.1 (3.1)
  pgfrcs.sty    2019/01/05 v3.1 (3.1)
```

Could this be the problem?

Any pdf file can be used to run the above.  Since I can't attach a PDF file here. So you can use any pdf file.

The code above has been working for very long time with no problem. It only failed now on the new linux after I did fresh install of latest TL 2018.

Comment: The above code is meant to work only on lualatex. It will not work on pdflatex. The `\saveimageresource` only works on lualatex. I only use lualatex.

Comment: I see.  Try `\the\lastsavedimageresourcepages`.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/507/

Comment: @JosephWright long time ago, I remember I used to use `\pdfximage` and that worked in lualatex and also in pdflatex. Then something happened, I do not know when, may be 1-2 years ago? Where `\pdfximage` stopped working in lualatex. So I googled and found I can use `\saveimageresource` and  `\lastsavedimageresourcepages` instead to make lualatex happy. That is why.

Comment: @Nasser Yes, primitives were renamed in LuaTeX 0.90: https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb37-1/tb115hagen-pdf.pdf

Comment: @Nasser, you can `\usepackage{luatex85}` which does among others `\let\pdflastximagepages  \lastsavedimageresourcepages` and keep same sources apart from that added package. (and it does `\let\pdfximage           \saveimageresource` as well)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are observing is a bug in PGF: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/507/

This is the broken commit: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/git/ci/acdfa1450bd2beda4d6865bb2717e4d6f628c875/

For now the workaround is either to prefix registers with `\the` or restore an internal definition from an old version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeatletter
\def\pgffor@dots@value@process#1{%
        \expandafter\pgffor@dots@stripcontext#1\pgffor@@stop%
        \expandafter\pgffor@dots@charcheck\pgffor@dotsvalue\pgffor@@stop%
  \let#1=\pgffor@dotsvalue% 
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\saveimageresource{example-image-a.pdf}
\foreach \n in {1,...,\lastsavedimageresourcepages} { }
\end{document}
```

<strike>However, then things like `\foreach \n in {1,...,1e+1} { }` will no longer work.</strike> This was only introduced in PGF 3.1, so it wouldn't have worked before anyway.

Comment: Fixed in next PGF version: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/git/ci/d7770565de48f46b5f6226783d9552e75367b595/

Comment: fyi, I just install TL 2019 and I still get same error `You can't use \lastsavedimageresourcepages in vertical mode` so still need to use your fix macro above to make the code works. I thought this will be fixed in TL 2019? thanks.

Comment: @Nasser There hasn't been a new release since, but you can install the development version.  Instructions can be found here: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf#installation